# MVC Localization Multi Language with Querystring

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, multilingual

I have a little bit problem with my code. I don't have any problem with routing but I would like to create *auto language* => when querystring changes than cookie will change and it effects to Culture.

I did this on asp.net web project with ovveride method but i cound't do it on mvc application. So, language changes will be easy. If you guys can help for ASP.NET MVC project, i'll be happy.

My Global.asax Code for this situation:

```
 protected void Application_BeginRequest()
    {

        var routes = RouteTable.Routes;

        var httpContext = Request.RequestContext.HttpContext;
        if (httpContext == null) return;

        var routeData = routes.GetRouteData(httpContext);

        var lang_route = routeData.Values["lang"] as string;
        var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo(lang_route);


        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;

        var lang_cookie = new HttpCookie("lang", cultureInfo.Name);
        lang_cookie.Expires.AddMonths(1);
        Response.Cookies.Add(lang_cookie);       
    }
```

This code is working but sometimes it says "null" and don't work. How can we fixed this. Thanks,

Comment: This blog post by Nadeem Afana helped me a lot when creating a mult-language mvc site. Checkout out how he implements the basecontroller and homecontroller. http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx